# Laravel: How to use foreach loop to decrease stock based on order quantity

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

I'm having trouble getting the `quantity` of the ordered products to update the `stock` quantity based on pivot table `order_items`.

**Order Model**

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'order_items', 'order_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('quantity', 'price')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**OrderItem Model**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

**Product Model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class,'order_items', 'order_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('quantity', 'price')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**OrderController (Updated)**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = new Order();
    $order->order_number = uniqid('Order #');
    ...
    $order->save();
    
    $cartItems = \Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item)
    {
        $order->items()->attach($item->id, [
            'price'=> $item->price,
            'quantity'=> $item->quantity
        ]);
    }

    // Update stock quantity
    foreach ($order->items as $prod) {
    {
        dd($order->items);
        $newStock = $prod->stock - $item->quantity;
        $prod->update(['stock' => $newStock]);
    }
    
    ...

}
```

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#598 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Product {#1159 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Product {#754 ▼
      #table: "products"
      #translatable: array:17 [▶]
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:16 [▼
        "id" => 24
        "shop_id" => 1
        "cat_id" => 19
        "child_cat_id" => 5
        "name" => "Facilis sit saepe."
        "slug" => "voluptatum-rem-doloribus-eligendi-porro-molestiae-sapiente-ut-aut"
        "summary" => "Quidem repudiandae voluptate explicabo sed voluptates impedit explicabo vel quis."
        "description" => "Sint corporis sed velit velit. Qui qui quibusdam sint. Commodi facere similique voluptas commodi rerum omnis incidunt qui. Est exercitationem odit id dignissimo ▶"
        "image" => "https://via.placeholder.com/400x200.png/007799?text=corrupti"
        "images" => "https://via.placeholder.com/400x200.png/00ccaa?text=nihil"
        "price" => 67.24
        "stock" => 4  // Product stock
        "condition" => "popular"
        "publish" => 1
        "created_at" => "2021-04-26 20:21:42"
        "updated_at" => "2021-04-26 20:21:42"
      ]
      #original: array:22 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to query your database inside the `foreach` to obtain the current `Product` as you already have access to it on your `items`.

You can use a classic `foreach` or you can use the [`each`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-each) method on the `items` collection.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    // iterate (loop) over each item in the order items collection
    $order->items->each(function ($item) {
        // deduct the quantity of the item for this order
        // from the stock of the product and update the new stock
        $item->update(['stock' => ($item->stock - $item->pivot->quantity)]);
    });

    // ...
}
```

On a side note, try to be consistent in your naming and use framework conventions where possible. You have a model named `Product` but you refer to instances of `Product` as `$item`. I know this seems like something very minor, however, consider a new developer or someone who has never seen your code or you returning to the code in 6 months and seeing `$item` then expecting to find an `Item` model.

Comment: This not working on my side, the stock quantity remains the same.

Comment: @March Can you update your question to include exactly what you tried with my example?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that might be causing an issue inside your controller.

Try the below code to see if that works for you.

- Removed the parentheses from `$order->items()`
- Changed the `$prod` query from **get** to **first**

  - Get returns a collection of results, first will return a single one.

**Updated my answer**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ....

    // Update stock quantity
    foreach ($order->items as $prod)
    {
        $newStock = $item->stock - $item->pivot->quantity;
        $prod->update(['stock' => $newStock]);
    }
    
    ...

}
```

Comment: Updated my answer, if that still doesn't give you the intended results check the output of `$order->items`

Comment: This returns only one record, however, the expected result should be in 2 for example, in `#items: array:2 [▼`. and the stock in my `products` also remains the same.

Comment: It gets the intended results for `$order->items` but the stock doesn't update.

Comment: Is the `$item` variable inside the loop supposed to relate to a single `$order->items` or do you define it elsewhere inside your controller?